# Python check json file with variables

Tags: python, json, loops, for-loop, variables

I have a json file which has 18 substrings like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVWuw.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLlRX.png

But I have more json files who have different number of these substrings. So I did this to find how many there are in the text:

```
import json

json_str = open('jsonfile.txt', 'r').read()

contact = json.loads(json_str)
```

So GraphImages_total is 18
.
Every substring has comments --> data --> 0 --> owner --> username
So I want to print the username.

```
comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][0]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"]
print(comment_author)
```

This is for GraphImages_total = 0
But I want to do it for all of them.

So I need a way to make it like this:

```
for graph_image in contact['GraphImages']:
    comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][graph_image]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"]
    print(comment_author)
```

But I get this error:

```
comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][graph_image]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"]IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: `for graph_image in contact['GraphImages']: print(graph_image)`…!

Comment: This is not what I want exactly. I want to make it like this:
comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][0]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"] ///

comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][1]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"] ///

comment_author = contact["GraphImages"][2]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"] ///

etc..

Comment: No, I did not give you the full solution, I *hinted* at where you need to go. You want to iterate over a list. Use a simple `for .. in ..` for that. No need for `range`. You take it from here.

Comment: Oh,yeah,this is good to make it more simple. So I did this:

x = 0 ///
for graph_image in contact['GraphImages']: ///
  print(contact["GraphImages"][x]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"]) ///
  x = x + 1 /// But I still get IndexError: list index out of range :(

Comment: ‍♂️ No. Don't keep track of any `x`, especially not manually! With `for graph_image in contact['GraphImages']`, the variable `graph_image` *is* a graph image dict. You access everything else through it! Not through `contact['GraphImages'][x]`, but through `graph_image`. This way you're guaranteed to only loop through things which exist. Apply the same logic to further nested objects.

Comment: I think I'm starting understand your logic. Ok I will try

Comment: You are awsome mate!!! I followed your logic,but I could not find a way to not add an extra variable... I will submit it when finish ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
contact["GraphImages"][0]["comments"]["data"][0]["owner"]["username"]
                       ^                      ^
```

This indicates where the lists of unknown length are. The `GraphImages` and `data` keys hold lists. To iterate over a list, you use a `for .. in` statement as follows:

```
my_list = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
for item in my_list:
    print(item)
```

Note that you're using `item` directly. `item` will in turn become `'foo'`, `'bar'` and `'baz'` on each respective iteration of the loop. You don't need to use any numeric indices nor count up any `x` or `y`.

Applied to your situation, you need two such loops:

```
for graph_image in contact['GraphImages']:
    for comment in graph_image['comments']['data']:
        print(comment['text'], comment['owner']['username'])
```